# Windows local account without welcome settings created by powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, policy

I know I can simple create new local user account using a PowerShell command, during the time when i am logged into my admin account

```
$user_name = 'No_password_account
New-LocalUser -Name $user_name -NoPassword
```

When you try to log into this new account there is a welcome wizard, (similar to OOBE). I need to create account which will not show this welcome settings wizard.

Is there any option how do that? e.g. via registry or PowerShell script which will create all standard folder structures and it will set Welcome Settings Wizard as done.

After searching the internet, it looks there is no way to do it, all pages only describe way for OOBE for first run system...

Comment: Try with Local GPO Config or create a RegKey: [Disable First User Sign-In Animation in Windows 10 and 11](https://woshub.com/disable-first-signin-animation-windows/)

Comment: it looks interest but i see i will need to have full account prepare before first login, i mean i need to copy some support scripts directly to desktop and windows\startup folder which need to run after first logon, so that generation i need to have done in time when i will create that account, i mean - is there some call which will prepare whole account profile settings etc before first login?

Comment: with this registry settings i went trought welcome wizard but there is still one more step which this registry setting does not solve - privacy settings  so need to find if there is option to allow it also by registry before.                                                   New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name EnableFirstLogonAnimation -Value 0 -Force

Comment: Have you tried to set this settings?
https://howtomanagedevices.com/windows-10/3654/how-to-disable-privacy-settings-experience-at-first-sign-in-in-windows-10/